# Windows system tray icon not clear after update

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to add a notification icon to system tray to show my application special status.

```
If showTrayIcon Then
    trayIcon.Visible = True
Else
    trayIcon.Visible = False
End If
```

After hide the icon it still shows on the system tray. Unless the mouse move on it. This can be a problem of Windows OS. I'm asking here, is there a way to fix this in my side?

Comment: try `trayIcon.Visible = false`, `trayIcon.icon = nothing`  and 
`trayIcon.Dispose()`

Comment: @Devcon it works.